# I2C slave: how to change control of SDA line from testbench to DUT to act as output?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, i2c

```
module I2C_SLAVEl_TB();
reg clock, reset_l;
wire SCL; // FROM SCL GENERATOR
wire SDA;
reg sda_tb, sda_drive;

SCL_GENERATOR scl_generator_inst(clock, reset_l_generator, SCL);
I2C_SLAVE i2c_slave_inst(reset_l, SCL, SDA);

assign SDA = (sda_drive) ? 1'bz : sda_tb;

initial
begin
    reset_l = 1'b0;
    
    i2c_slave_inst.busy = 1'b0;
    clock = 1'b0;
    forever #5 clock = ~clock;
end

initial
begin
    sda_drive = 1'b1;
    
    #2500 reset_l = 1'b1;
    #3000 sda_drive = 1'b0;
    sda_tb = 1'b1;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b1;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b0;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b1;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b0;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b1;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b0;
    #3995 sda_tb = 1'b1; // LAST BIT OF ADDRESS INDICATES READ WRITE OPERATION. (0 = WRITE AND 1 = READ)
    
    sda_drive = 1'b1;
end
endmodule
```

***[image: strong text]***

I'm getting a high impedance line in the waveforms as you can see when I'm attempting to change the control of `SDA` from testbench to DUT.

NOTE: The delays can be ignored because it is so because of the project specifications given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following line:

```
assign SDA = (sda_drive) ? 1'bz : sda_tb;
```

this means:

- When `sda_drive`=0, the testbench should drive the `SDA` signal, and the `I2C_SLAVE` design should be 1'bz
- When `sda_drive`=1, the `I2C_SLAVE` design should drive the `SDA` signal and the testbench should be 1'bz

Instead of using a `reg` for `sda_drive` in the testbench, you could look inside the design for a comparable signal.  For example, if the design has a signal named `sda_out_en`, then you could create a `wire` in the testbench like:

```
wire sda_drive = ~i2c_slave_inst.sda_out_en;
```

This assures that either the testbench or the design is driving `SDA` (but never both at the same time).

Then you should remove all other assignments to `sda_drive` in the testbench.